# Yii multiple update queries

Tags: mysql, yii, phpquery

below update query run in phpmyadmin. update all rows correctly.

```
SET @bal = 0;
UPDATE banking SET bank_bal = @bal := @bal + (cr_amt - dr_amt) WHERE `bank_account_id` = 2
```

I tried above query in yii:

```
$update = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->update('banking', 
    array(
        'bank_bal'=>new CDbExpression("@bal := @bal + (cr_amt - dr_amt)")
    ),
    'bank_account_id=:id',
    array(':id'=>$acc)
);
```

update balance column as 0 of all rows. I know @bal not set. where I put this mysql line  SET @bal = 0. Anybody can help.

Comment: just create separate sql query before update query (SET @bal = 0;)

Answer (score 0):

at this place:

```
'bank_bal'=>new CDbExpression("@bal := @bal + (cr_amt - dr_amt)",array('@bal'=>$value))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @Janz I get error Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens. I create separate query before update as explain juris. it's works.

Answer (score 0):

just create separate sql query before update query (SET @bal = 0;)